# Dynamically add nested list to object

Tags: c#

I need to add a nested list to an object. I have this shopping cart with list of items. I am trying to send that list of items together with other properties as a string object. I looped through my list as

```
public string SendOrderEmailBody()
        {
            var connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
            var orderData = connection.Table<ItemCartModel>().ToList();
            float totalCost = 0f;
            List<PlaceOrderModel> orderModel = new List<PlaceOrderModel>();
            for (int i = 0; i < orderData.Count; i++)
            {
                totalCost += (orderData[i].ItemPrice * orderData[i].ItemQuantity);
                orderModel = new List<PlaceOrderModel>
                {
                    new PlaceOrderModel()
                    {
                        PlacedOrderItemname = orderData[i].ItemName,
                        PlacedOrderQuantity = orderData[i].ItemQuantity,
                        PlacedOrderItemDough = orderData[i].ItemDough,
                        PlacedOrderItemSauce = orderData[i].ItemSauce,
                        PlacedOrderItemPrice = orderData[i].ItemPrice
                    }
                };
                TotalCost = totalCost;
            }
            Order OrderDetails = new Order
            {
                UserName = NameText,
                UserPhone = PhoneText,
                OrderItems = orderModel,
                TotalCost = totalCost
            };
            var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(OrderDetails);
            return content;
        }
```

This method does send the list but only the last item from my cart is being sent.
My order model is

```
public class Order
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string UserPhone { get; set; }
        public float TotalCost { get; set; }
        public List<PlaceOrderModel> OrderItems { get; set; }
    }
```

My solution is only looping through the for loop and not adding the entire cart item to orderModel.

Comment: I think this line is wrong `orderModel = new List<PlaceOrderModel>` as you are newing up your list on each loop. Try using `orderModel.Add()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why only the last item is persisting on your list is because of the line `orderModel = new List<PlaceOrderModel>` which instantiates a new list of place order model.

A quick solution would be adding an item instead of re-instantiating the `orderModel`.

```
orderModel.Add(new PlaceOrderModel()
{
    PlacedOrderItemname = orderData[i].ItemName,
    PlacedOrderQuantity = orderData[i].ItemQuantity,
    PlacedOrderItemDough = orderData[i].ItemDough,
    PlacedOrderItemSauce = orderData[i].ItemSauce,
    PlacedOrderItemPrice = orderData[i].ItemPrice
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked but I swear I'd tried this as well yesterday. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: @ShanksLimbu Tha's fine. We all have that moment as software engineers